# IndexError: tuple index out of range in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am doing some matrix value replacement using numpy and pandas. My main goal is to match the index value from matrix ds2 into ds1 and replace it with corresponding value. this code snippet works as expect.

```
def missingValueProcessing(self ):
    ds1 = [[ 4, 13,  6,  9],
          [ 7, 12,  5,  7],
          [ 7,  0,  4, 22],
          [ 9,  8, 12,  0]]

    ds2 = [[ 4,  1],
           [ 5,  3],
           [ 6,  1],
           [ 7,  2],
           [ 8,  2],
           [ 9,  3],
           [12,  1],
           [13,  2],
           [22,  3]]

    ds1= pd.DataFrame(ds1)
    ds2= pd.DataFrame(ds2)

    #Processing ds1 by replacing
    ds2.groupby(0, as_index=False).mean()
    C = np.where(ds1.values.ravel()[:, None] == ds2.values[:, 0])
    print C[1]
```

when I do same on my actual similar large matrices

```
ds2 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/1692f1f76718c35e939f/raw/6f6b348ab0879b702e1c3c5e362e9d2062e9e9bc/ds2', header=None, sep=' ')

ds1 = pd.read_table('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/karimkhanp/9527bad750fbe75e072c/raw/ds1', sep=' ', header=None)
```

it gives

```
  File "missing_value.py", line 15, in missingValueProcessing
    print C[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

any suggestion would be much appreciable,

Comment: How about do `_,C = np.where(ds1.values.ravel()[:, None] == ds2.values[:, 0])`?

Comment: @Divakar: thanks but already tried it, it also gives same error in `_,C = np.where(ds1.values.ravel()[:, None] == ds2.values[:, 0])` itself

Comment: Is the error after running the suggested code, in creating `C` or printing `C`?

Comment: @Divakar: in my suggested code it gives error in printing `C[1]`, while in code suggested by you, it gives in creating `C` itself

Comment: @Divakar: I appreciate any suggestion if you have

Comment: At my end (python3.4), it works fine, though it gives empty array as output, because no match was found.

Comment: In my python2.7 works fine too. What is your python version?

Comment: my versions `Python 2.7.3
numpy - 1.9.2
pandas - 0.15.2`